# Who is uncle Fester?

Tags: adams-family

In the Adams Family movies, we know Uncle Fester as Fester Adams, Gomez Adams older brother. But, I just watched S2 E1 & E2 of the Adams Family TV show from the 60's and they have Fester has Morticia's uncle. Morticia's last name was not Adams until her and Gomez got married.

Why was it changed so that Fester was Gomez's brother for the movies?

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be a definitive answer to this. I suspect that it boils down to: they wanted the long-lost brother plot, and they wanted Fester as a character. So, why not just combine those two characters into one?

Comment: Also, in the original comics,  he's not named at all, none of them are.

Comment: Because they could and nobody in the target audience was alive to have seen the 60s Adams Family to complain about modern day continuity. (Though it’s interesting the whole series has been officially uploaded to youtube. ) Unless the kids happened to grow up in a place where 60s show reruns were still common place..it’s unlikely anyone actually remembered or knew uncle fester was Morticas brother regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from one of the [wiki's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Fester):

> In the original sitcom of the 1960s, Fester is said to be Morticia's
> maternal uncle (his name rhymes with Morticia's mother Hester's), but
> from the 1970s onward, he is Gomez's brother. In all adaptations, he
> is either uncle or great-uncle to Wednesday and Pugsley.
>
> In the 1960s television series, Fester (played by Jackie Coogan) is
> uncle to Morticia Addams. In one episode, he became perplexed when
> asked his last name, suggesting he has somehow forgotten it. In
> several episodes, Fester refers to the Addams lineage as if it were
> his own, possibly implying some degree of intertwined consanguinity in
> both their family lines, but the flashbacks in the episodes
> "Morticia's Romance, Parts 1 and 2," clearly establish him as
> Morticia's uncle, brother of her mother, Hester Frump, a.k.a. Granny
> Frump (Margaret Hamilton), whose maiden name was similarly unrevealed.
> In various episodes, he was a partner in typical sitcom schemes with
> Gomez, Morticia, or Grandmama Addams, indicating no real preference
> for any family member over others.
>
> In the movie, The Addams Family, Fester (played by Christopher Lloyd)
> is the long-lost brother of Gomez Addams.

As for *why*, it's strictly about adaptation.  Why are remakes different from the original movies?  It's just a twist a writer thought could make their version more unique.

Comment: So it wasn't even the movie, it was the show that changed it up as well? Interesting.